# Test cases pass when run individually and fail when run together

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, test-class

Showing error in class where i am trying to get the values of static ArrayList<ArrayList> adjacent_list_train=new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
which is returning error like: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1. The issue is with the static variable?

```
class Node{

    
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<TrainVertices>> adjacent_list_train=new ArrayList<ArrayList<TrainVertices>>(); 
public void CList(){
      //error thrown at the following line
    if(FlightEdges.size>0) {
            if(!adjacent_list.isEmpty()) {
                for(int i=0;i<adjacent_list.size();i++) {
//error line
                    ArrayList<FlightEdges> fe_al=adjacent_list.get(i);
}
}
```

As per my observation it is something about static variable being accessed in multiple test class.  As i am new to junit testing can you please tell what is wrong with the test class

Comment: Why does `Node` have a `static` variable? `static` is for variables that are associated with the class and not with an individual instance. Does every `Node` have the same `adjancent_list_train`? If not, then this should not be `static`.

Comment: With that said, I suggest you debug your code to figure out why it is behaving differently than you expect or want. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has tips to get you started.

Comment: It is for constructing a graph where this field is accessed by another classes for getting the adjacent node value

Comment: Is the list shared by every `Node` instance? Or should each `Node` have its own list? This is the only question that is important when deciding whether or not to use `static`. Where it is accessed is irrelevant.

Comment: Another question to ask: does `adjacent_list_train` even belong in `Node` at all? If other classes need to access it then maybe this list belongs somewhere else. One way to figure this out is to describe what a `Node` is? What does this class represent? I assume it is a node in a graph. So then take a step back and think about how you are representing a graph in code. Which representation are you using here? It looks like you have `TrainVertices` and `FlightEdges` as two other classes. For a general graph data structure, you should have much more generic names such as `Vertex` and `Edge`.

Comment: Also be sure to use consistent naming. Decide now whether to use thet name `Node` or `Vertex` and stick with it. Don't mix them as you are here. This leads to pain and sufferinig as you continue on this project.

Comment: it needs to be static because every time the adjacent list input is taken from the user it needs to hold all the values in it. This static field is accessed later to other class for itrating over this list and getting all the adjacent values from the list

Comment: are you manipulating adjacent_list_train in different method? if yes, then if will cause the issue. If you want to test it then you have to add as much element in the list as removed by some test.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: @KhushbooPatel None of your explanation so far justifies using `static` here. Does every `Node` object need the exact same `adjacent_list_train`? This is the only question you should answer to decide if `static` is correct here.